# Existing library to reproduce zoom-in imageView effect of Foursquare android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, uiimageview, android-animation, android-kenburnsview

I am searching a library or an existing code which reproduce the zoom-in / zoom-out imageview effect which can be found in Foursquare Android application.

Here is the effect that i would like to reproduce : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5uiJlSSk9dZclZENm1pZTVlaEk/edit?usp=sharing

This effect produce 2 things :

- A slow zoom out in the image ;
- And in the same time, a slow translation animation

Could you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think thats called the Ken Burns effect.

[Try this](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView)

Its a custom imageview library

Answer (score 1):

You need to play with animations on your ImageView for animation tutorials visit
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/ , http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

implement these animation with you ImageView by calling

```
 ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.youranimation);
        image1.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Thats called the Ken Burns effect.

I think [this library](https://github.com/gotokatsuya/KenBurnsView) is better.

You can load a url into ImageView by using this library.